# How can the wrong override method be called through multiple levels of inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following Java class structure. (JDK 1.6.0_21)

```
Class C extends B` {
  //Nothing relevant
}

Class B extends A {
  public void clear() {
    // whatever
  }
}

Class A {
  public void clear() {
    // whatever
  }
}
```

I had an object c of type C. When I was calling `c.clear()`, it was calling the `clear()` method from class `A`, not class `B`. After more than a few clean and builds, it started using the clear method on class `B`, which is as expected.

Before anyone states "You musn't have rebuilt after changing class A, B or C". These classes haven't changed in 3 years. I even added debug lines to prove it was calling `A.clear()`, which also proves that it had all been recompiled.

Does anyone know of any reason it would have been calling `A.clear()` instead of `B.clear()`, remembering that all three of these classes haven't changed in years?

EDIT: Class A and B are part of a library that end up in a jar file. Class `C` is in a Java Application. Both these projects are checked out in Eclipse and were compiled multiple times with this issue - as I was adding debug in the library and debug in the Java app.

EDIT AGAIN: The `clear()` method in Class `B` does NOT use `super.clear()`, and neither is it supposed to.

FINAL EDIT: The answer has to be that there was some kind of compilation/environment issue - if Java's JDK had some kind of flaw effecting the inheritance model there would be much more heard of it. Without exposing the entirety of the project, I don't think there's much more anyone can do. Thanks to those who answered!

Comment: What environment are you running it in?  App server?  Command line?  Are you making use of class loaders?

Comment: This is all done in Eclipse 3.6
Class A and B are in a library that is ever so rarely modified. I just checked CVS, and these two classes haven't changed since 2005.
Class C is in an application that uses the library that contains class A and B. Class C hasn't changed since 2003.

Comment: If you haven't changed any of this in 3 years then how has a problem developed? Is there something wacky in your build system that might have allowed someone to compile against a separate jar? What about a scenario where a developer is locally testing a variant of A/B and compiles C against that (I"ve seen build systems bad enough to allow that)? (longshot)are you determining any classes through reflection?

Comment: I've been tracking backwards and we do actually use a class loader to call the main method of the java application that contains class C. Don't think that changes anything, but I don't know much about class loaders. This might be a sorry case where, without seeing all kazillion lines of the awful code in this project there's not much you helpful guys can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I even added debug lines to prove it was calling A.clear(), which also proves that it had all been recompiled.

No it doesn't. The debugger can run with different code than the one deployed. You'll just be seeing the wrong lines, and in the worst case - the same lines (if the code changes didn't move anything around)

Next time make sure the *date* of the files/jars is not in the past.

Comment: I personally understood "debug lines" as calls to System.out.println() or calls to logger.debug(), not the use of a debugger.

Comment: @Damien perhaps you are right. But initially I thought of it as a breakpoint. Anyway, without seeing where they have been, I can't say whether the have been placed correctly.

Comment: The answer has to be that there was some kind of compilation issue, if Java's JDK had some kind of flaw effecting the inheritance model there would be much more heard of it.